# Does grep and friends have a way to match strings as if shell file name globbing in stead of regex

Tags: grep, regex, filename

Effectively I'm trying to search a text file containing "file names" and want to match as if shell file globbing were in effect.

Shell file globbing is much simpler than regular expressions, so I need some kind of

`grep "data??.*" < list_of_filenames`

And bonus points if I can do it with AWK, eg something along the lines of

`awk -F/ '$NF ~ /data??.*/ {print $0}' < list_of_filenames`

to print the line when the last part of the line delimited by / matches the patern "data??.*"

Comment: Related: [Can globbing be used to search file contents?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445515/can-globbing-be-used-to-search-file-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Anything globs can do can also be expressed as a regular expression. So although the answer to your question is no, tools like `grep` only do strings and regular expressions, that shouldn't be a problem. Regexes are a much more pwoerful tools  than globs.

For the example in your question where you want something that begins with `data`, then any two characters, then a `.` and then 0 or more characters until the end of the line (that's what your expression would match if used as a glob), the equivalent regular expression is:

```
^data..\..*
```

So you can use that in `grep` or in `awk` (you don't need the `print`, by the way, the default action when something evaluates to true in awk is to print the current line):

```
awk -F/ '$NF ~ /^data..\..*/' list_of_filenames
```