# Setting local variables from array elements

Tags: bash

I am passing the variable `akms` to the function named `sufx`.  I am able te correctly capture the second array element and set the variable `fskl`.

I want the capability of setting the variable `verbiage` according to the numeric value of `-v`.  How can I do this for the function `sufx` ?  Currently `verbiage` is just taking a string value.

```
akms=("-v 3" "INCLUDE")
sufx akms
```

Here is the function

```
sufx ()
{
  typeset -n _akms="$1"

  ## Capture INCLUDE or EXCLUDE option for grep
  local fskl="" verbiage=0
  for s in "${_akms[@]}"; do
     case $s in
       ("XCL"|"INCL"|"INCLUDE") fskl="INCLUDE" ;;
       ("NCL"|"EXCL"|"EXCLUDE") fskl="EXCLUDE" ;;
       (*) verbiage=${s#*-v} ;;
      esac
  done

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you mean:

1. How to check if an array element is of the pattern `-v` then "anything" then "numeric character/s" ... You can do this using a sub-string regular expression match with `bash`'s extended test brackets and the `=~` regex operator i.e. `[[ "$element" =~ regex ]]`.
2. How to extract only the numeric characters of a string stored in a parameter ... You can do this using `bash`'s parameter expansion to exclude all non-numeric characters with e.g. `"${parameter//[^0-9]}"`.

So, combining the above two methods:

```bash
$ array=("-v 3" "INCLUDE")

$ for i in "${array[@]}"
  do
  if [[ "$i" =~ "-v".*[0-9]{1,} ]]
    then
    var="${i//[^0-9]}"
    echo "$var"
    echo "$((var+2))"
    fi
  done

# Output:
3
5
```

Or, using a globbing pattern with `case ... esac` for example:

```bash
$ array=("-v 3" "INCLUDE")

$ for i in "${array[@]}"
  do
  case "$i" in
   [-][v]*[0-9] ) var="${i//[^0-9]}" && echo -e "$var\n$((var+2))" ;;
  esac
  done

# Output
3
5
```

Please also see [Can globbing be used to search file contents?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1445515)

Comment: I would like to use a glob pattern that I can use within the case statement I am using.

Comment: Have included `(-v([[:blank:]])+([0-9])+) verbiage="${s//[^0-9]}" ;;` in the case statement, but there is some syntax problem with it.

Comment: @Backy That is a regular expression pattern and not a globbing pattern … please see the linked post for how to use globbing patterns with `case` and how to use regular expression patterns with extended test brackets `[[ … =~ … ]]`

Comment: @Backy I added an example with `case ... esac`

Comment: Quite right, the special characters go in front of the bracket expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest passing the `"-v 3"` string as a separate option letter + option argument `"-v" "3"`. Then you can use the bash shell's built-in option parser `getopts` to process them:

```
sufx ()
{
    typeset -n _akms="$1"

    local verbiage=0 fskl="" 

    ## process option arguments
    local OPTIND=1
    while getopts ':v:' opt "${_akms[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            (v) verbiage=$OPTARG
                ;;
            (*) echo "unkown option: $opt" 1>&2
                ;;
        esac
    done
    
    ## process remaining non-option arguments
    for s in "${_akms[@]:$((OPTIND-1))}"
    do
        case $s in
           ("XCL"|"INCL"|"INCLUDE") fskl="INCLUDE"
           ;;
           ("NCL"|"EXCL"|"EXCLUDE") fskl="EXCLUDE"
           ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

The usage becomes

```
akms=("-v" "3" "INCLUDE")

sufx akms
```

You could even use `akms=("-v" "3" -- "INCLUDE")` to explicitly mark the end of options (which would allow you to use non-option arguments starting with a dash).