# Regular expression to match a concatenation of fixed strings, and alternative expressions

Tags: bash, regex, filename

I mean to match (with `ls`, `rm`, etc.) files with names `test10` to `test18`, `test30` to `test38`, `test22` to `test23`, with a single regex, in bash.
I tried many variants around

```
$ ll "test([1,3][0-8]|22|23)"
```

but I couldn't make it work.
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: As a RegEx side note, it might be worth noting that `,` in `[1,3]` will be matched literally and will not be treated as a special character like e.g. the class range character `-`  (I just got the impression you are trying to use it in a special way) ... Also, Bash (and alike shells) can actually do RegEx matching ... See for example [Can globbing be used to search file contents?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1445515) ... However, in your use case, what you want is indeed shell filename globbing or brace expansion and not RegEx matching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, shells uses *glob patterns*, not regular expressions<sup>1</sup>. In bash, you could use a ksh-style *extended* glob (enabled by default in an interactive bash shell - in a script, you will need to set with `shopt -s extglob`):

```
ls test@([13][0-8]|2[23])
```

or

```
ls test@(1[0-8]|2[23]|3[0-8])
```

In zsh, you could use numeric ranges instead (although it supports ksh-style extended globs as well):

```
ls test(<10-18>|<22-23>|<30-38>)
```

Alternatively, you could use brace expansion (in both bash and zsh) - but note this doesn't actually perform matching so you will get errors unless all the named files are actually present:

```
ls test{{1,3}{0..8},22,23}
```

---

1. *Coincidentally*, `([13][0-8]|2[23])` and `(1[0-8]|2[23]|3[0-8])` are also valid extended regular expressions, so you could use them in a `find` expression for example:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/test([13][0-8]|2[23])'
   ```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use bash. I will try this. Is there any alternative without `shopt -s extglob`?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio brace expansion will work in bash without extglob - however you will likely find that extglob is on by default in your interactive shell so you should only need to set it explicitly inside a script.

Comment: Your suggestion works!